# Are generic type parameters converted to Object for raw types?

Tags: java, generics

Consider this piece of code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat<Integer> cat = new Cat();
        Integer i= cat.meow();
        cat.var = 6;
    }
}
public class Cat<E> {
    public E var;
    public E meow() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

As per my understanding since I've not specified the type parameter on LHS, it would be taken as `Object`. And `Cat` should become `Cat<Object>` because for the variable declaration to make any sense T must translate to a Class/Interface reference. Is this a correct understanding of how it works? **How is type parameter T handled in case of raw types?**

I've discussed this on chat and got [following](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22993150#22993150) explanation which is way over my head:

> Generics works because types are erased. Consider T an erasure of
> #0-capture-of-Object. When T isn't specified (rawtyped), it is #0-capture-of-(nothing)

What does `#0-capture-of-(nothing)` mean?

**Side note:** since generic types are implemented as compile time transformations it would be easier to understand them if one could see the final translated code. Does anyone know a way to see the translated code (not byte code) for a class?

Comment: `Does anyone know a way to see the translated code (not byte code) for a class?` Simply use a decompiler like [`JD`](http://jd.benow.ca/) to decompile `Main.class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No,

raw types are not as if they are paramterized with `Object`, nor are they like wildcard types (`<?>`).
For raw types, generics are *turned off*.

This code is compiles (with warnings):

```
Cat c1 = new Cat<String>();
Cat<Integer> c2 = c1;
```

This code does not:

```
Cat<? extends Object> c1 = new Cat<String>(); // btw: this is the same as Cat<?>
Cat<Integer> c2 = c1; // error
```

neither does this:

```
Cat<Object> c1 = new Cat();
Cat<Integer> c2 = c1; // error
```

### As for the type of `var`:

the type of the field after compilation is whatever the upper-bound of the parameter is (`Object` if none is specified). But what does the compiler do if we access `var`?

```
Cat<String> c1 = ...
String c1Var = c1.var;
```

This code compiles without error, but what the compiler will actually compile is this:

```
Cat c1 = ...
String c1Var = (String) c1.var;
```

As you can see, `var` is always treated as a field of type `Object`, but **with generics, the compiler automatically inserts type-safe casts**. **That's all**. If you use raw types, you have to do it yourself. Either way, when you put a `Cat` that stores an integer in a `Cat<String>` variable, you will only get a runtime exception if you try to read `var`.

### A quiz

Now look at the declaration of [Collections.max](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.max%28java.util.Collection%29). Why do you think the parameter is defined as `T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>`?

Answer encoded in [rot13](http://rot13.com):

> Fb gung nsgre pbzcvyngvba gur erghea glcr vf `Bowrpg`, abg `Pbzcnenoyr`. Guvf vf arrqrq sbe onpxjneqf pbzcngvovyvgl (gur zrgubq vgfrys vf byqre guna trarevpf).

### Edit:

Here is another good example that I just stumbled upon:

```
class Foo<T> {
    public <V> V bar(V v) { return v; }
}

//compiles
Foo<Object> foo = new Foo<Object>();
Integer i = foo.bar(1);

//compiles
Foo<?> foo = new Foo<String>();
Integer i = foo.bar(1);

// fails
Foo foo = new Foo();
Integer i = foo.bar(1); // error: Object cannot be converted to Integer
```

Using no parameters disables generics entirely.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've written an explanation from my own perspective. Could you please review it to check if I've got it right?

Answer (score 1):

This code is valid:

```
Cat c = new Cat<Integer>();
```

`c` is now of the Raw Type `Cat`.
This is not valid:

```
Cat<Object> c = new Cat<Integer>(); // Compiler error
```

So, it's not exactly the same. Though you can, after the first line, do things like:

```
c.var = 5;
System.out.println(c.var);
c.var = 1;
System.out.println(c.var);
c.var = "test";
System.out.println(c.var);
```

Outputs:

```
5
1
test
```

Comment: So `T` has become `Object`?

Comment: With regards to the type of `var`, yes it is now `Object`.
But `c` is not of the same type as if it was declared as `Cat<Object>` as Cephalopod explains in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

`@Cephalopod` has provided the correct answer, however I'd like to expand on that with some of my own explanation.

> **for the variable declaration to make any sense T must translate to a Class/Interface reference.**

That is correct. Generics are a compile time transformation. Runtime system has no notion of abstract types. So before the class is loaded into memory the abstract type T must be replaced by an actual type reference.

Run the following code:

```
System.out.println(Cat.class.getMethod("meow").getReturnType());
System.out.println(Cat.class.getField("var").getType());
```

The output is:

```
class java.lang.Object 
class java.lang.Object
```

The formal type parameter `E` has been replaced with `Object`.

> **`Cat` should become `Cat<Object>`**

Wrong. `Cat` will stay `Cat`. Why? Look at the decompiled class file for `Main`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        Integer i = (Integer)cat.meow();
        cat.var = Integer.valueOf(6);
    }
}
```

The purpose of specifying formal type parameter with `<>` is to enable compiler to generate explicit casts.

When you say `new Cat()` it doesn't have to turn into anything, the compiler simply won't generate a cast and the method call would look like:

```
Integer i = cat.meow(); // No cast at all
```

> **Are generic type parameters converted to Object for raw types?**

To clarify what is being asked here, the above questions means: Is `E` replaced with `java.lang.Object` if I don't specify anything when instantiating `Cat`.

Actually `E` would be replaced with `java.lang.Object` even if you specified `<Integer>` when instantiating `Cat`. The replacement/transformation is done at compile time while the instantiation is at runtime. How you use the type isn't going to change its class definition.

Comment: I think you got it. I added a quiz to my answer; even if you can't solve it, you should be able to understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generic types defined in objects like the

```
Cat c = new Cat<Integer>();
```

are only intended to provide the compiler with the chance to check that the types will match at runtime.

Generic types assigned in class definitions are retained in the compiled class.

```
public class Cat<T extends Number>{}
```

Or

```
public class Intcat extends Cat<Integer>{}
```

The runtime knows that the generic argument is bound by Number in the first case and is Integer in the first case.

Answer (score 0):

I have no links to back this up, but I'd rather assume that `c` becomes raw type `Cat`, not `Cat<Object>`.
Raw types don't handle parameter T, which is why they are prone to errors.
javadoc says: A raw type is the name of a generic class or interface without any type arguments.

That chat log seems to mean exactly that, but in a confusing manner.

Answer (score 0):

I actually Do not know How it is actually implemented in the bytecode But from my understanding `Cat c = new Cat<Integer>();` Stores the new instance of `Cat` created by `new Cat<Integer>()` in the variable `c`. Now if you query `c` to know what is the type of `var` it will reply `Integer` and not `Object` because the instance that was created has a type of `Integer`.

Now If you execute `c.var = "Text";` and query c to know what is the type of `var`. It would reply `String`. This does not means that by default it is converting `<T>` to `Object`. It means that `c` does not know what is the type of `var`.

I feel that is why the `<?>` wild card is used. `Cat<?> c = new Cat<Integer>();` it would always convert `<T>` to `Object`. That is the reason why it is always advised not the use raw types for generics.

Comment: `Now if you query c to know what is the type of var it will reply Integer` in the end it must be only **one** type. If it's Integer how can you assign `String` to it?

Comment: That is the problem with raw types as they do not know the bounds of `<T>` So whatever comes in it assumes it to be correct as a result you can get all types of errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think Cat c is a RAW type and could be considered as a "wildcard type" like `Cat<?>`. Since `Cat<?>` is the supertype of each type of Cat including `Cat<Integer>`, `Cat c` may take a `new Cat<Integer>` object.

This is also mentioned here: [Interoperating with Legacy Code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/legacy.html)

"Most people's first instinct is that Collection really means Collection. However, as we saw earlier, it isn't safe to pass a Collection in a place where a Collection is required. It's more accurate to say that the type Collection denotes a collection of some unknown type, just like Collection."

...

"So raw types are very much like wildcard types, but they are not typechecked as stringently. This is a deliberate design decision, to allow generics to interoperate with pre-existing legacy code."