# Can the cast of Java Generics with @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") cause runtime exceptions

Tags: java, generics, suppress-warnings

I have 2 interfaces `Sub` and `Obs` as illustrated below:

```
public interface Sub<O extends Obs<? extends Sub>>{
   public void addObs(O o);

   public void removeObs(O o);

   public void notifyObs();
}

public interface Obs<S entends Sub<?>>{
   public void update(S s);
}
```

Now there are 2 concrete implementations of the above as class `Vie` which implements `Obs` and class `Mod` which implements `Sub` as below:

```
public class Mod implements Sub<Vie<Mod>>{

   private Vie<Mod>[] vies = new Vie<Mod>[0];//Here is the error.

   public void addObs(Vie<Mod> vie){
     vies = addToArray(vies, vie);
     //Some other code;
   }

   public void removeObs(Vie<Mod> vie){
     vies = removeFromArray(vies, vie);
     //Some other code;
   }

   public void notifyObs(){
      for(Vie<Mod> v : this.vies){
         v.update(this);
      } 
   }
}

public class Vie<M extends Mod> implements Obs<M>{

   private M mod;

   public void update(M){
      //some code;
   }

   public void setMod(M mod){
      this.mod.removeObs(this); //Here is the error.
      mod.addObs(this); //Here is the error.
      this.mod = mod;
   }
}
```

In the above code of `Mod` there is an error of initialisation of the array `vies`. The correction that is applicable is :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private Vie<Mod>[] vies = (Vie<Mod>[])new Vie<Mod>[0];
```

And for the `Vie` class's `setMod` method the correction that can be applied is:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void setMod(M mod){
   this.mod.removeObs((Vie<Mod>)this); 
   mod.addObs((Vie<Mod>)this); 
   this.mod = mod;
}
```

As we can see that both the above cases we had to explicitly type cast the instances before they could be used by the program also we had to add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` so that the compiler does not throw any compile error.

Now my understanding of `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` is that I am explicitly asking the compiler not to check the type of the instance of the variable at the compile time. If this is correct then can I run into any runtime `ClassCastException`?

Also can this above code be modified such that I do not require any `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`?

**Additional Info**

I have updated the code to show the utilisation of the variable `vies`. This above is a basic implementation of **Observer Pattern**. Kindly note that this is the complete implementation as far as the Observer Pattern is concerned. What I mean to say is in actual implementation the real classes inherits other classes and interfaces whose methods are not mentioned here. But as far as `vies` and `mod` variable is concerned, this is complete.

Comment: Why is `vies` an array? You won't have this problem when you make it a `List`: `List<Vie<Mod>> vies = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: @Jesper This is already implemented in that fashion. Ok If you could add something using `List<Vie<Mod>> vies = new ArrayList<>();` Please suggest me. I am posting some additional code.

Comment: I am not sure about this, but you can still get ClassCastExceptions if you are not careful with your methods etc.

Comment: @Blip what do you mean with "this is already implemented in that fashion"? In your code, `vies` is an [array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) instead of a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html).

Comment: @Jesper yes `vies` is an array of `Vie` object. This is already a part of an existing code. I am actually afraid that using `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` may at some point of time throw a `ClassCastException` at the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with creation of an array of a parameterized type has to do with the array not being able to check that elements added are the right type as arrays usually do. Since you only use the array inside the class and don't expose it to the outside, it's fine and you can just suppress the warning. The type you use and the suppression of the warning are internal implementation details of the class and outside code doesn't care.

The type mismatch of passing `this` to `removes()` and `addObs` is a bigger issue. `Vie<M>` and `Vie<Mod>` are incompatible types. It's not clear why you have `Vie` be generic. If you didn't make it generic, it would work:

```
public class Mod implements Sub<Vie> {

   private Vie[] vies = new Vie[0];

   public void addObs(Vie vie) {
     //vies = addToArray(vies, vie);
     //Some other code;
   }

   public void removeObs(Vie vie) {
     //vies = removeFromArray(vies, vie);
     //Some other code;
   }

   public void notifyObs() {
      for (Vie v : this.vies) {
         v.update(this);
      } 
   }
}

public class Vie implements Obs<Mod> {

   private Mod mod;

   public void update(Mod mod) {
      //some code;
   }

   public void setMod(Mod mod) {
      this.mod.removeObs(this);
      mod.addObs(this);
      this.mod = mod;
   }
}
```

If you want to be able to have this code work for `Mod` and `Vie` subclasses, then it would be more complicated.

Comment: kindly have a look above as I have completed the code concerning the utilisation of `vies` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler warning you are suppressing is designed to warn about possible errors due to type erasure. Type erasure means at run-time your parameterized classes are not parameterized, but plain types. This means that the runtime knows `Vie` is `Vie` but it can't check what object type it holds in `mod` (until you fetch it).

The general class of problems are explained here: [Java GenericsFAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ001). Your example is similar to the Wrapper example given.

Here is an example of the dangers of ignoring unchecked warnings using conventional classes:

```
    ArrayList<String> as = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> ai = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    ArrayList ao1;
    ArrayList ao2;

    as.add("Hello");

    ao1 = as;
    ao2 = ai;

    ao2.add(ao1.get(0));

    Integer i = ai.get(0); // Class cast exception, even though no casting done
```

Your code is vaguely similar and I think it helps to understand the above example to see what you are doing. You won't see any errors in the code you have supplied as you are putting `Vie<M extends Mod>` objects to a `Vie<Mod>` holder. The problem lies when you come get to things out of your `Vie<Mod>` holder and you assume they could be `Vie<ParticularM>` objects, which is not necessarily true.

You don't have any methods at the moment fetching the `Vie` objects, but if you did, at runtime the compiler would not be able to tell the exact type of the the object that `Vie` was wrapping, so any casts that you make to `Vie<M>` are really advice to the compiler and cannot actually be enforced.

In your code, it is all held together by the Vie class itself which moderates access to the Mod class and ensures (I think) that you are always putting consistent objects in the array.

But your code is not complete and you are only a step away from adding some piece of code that allows a `Vie<M2 extends Mod>` object to be put in an array where you think are `Vie<M1 extends Mod>` objects.

So, in summary, I think the current code is safe as it stands in isolation, but any changes could introduce errors that the compiler could not detect.

Comment: what you have demonstrated here is the danger of using **RAW TYPES** in generics not exactly what I have asked. I wanted to know whether **without using raw types** and casting it into known type with @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") is there any scope of an exception occuring?

Comment: Yes, but it amounts to the same thing. A raw type is just an thing of Objects, Object being a superclass of String and Integer. In your case, you have a thing of Mod, being a superclass of M (and presumably, other classes). In both cases, it is safe to add the subclass to a holder but not safe to get the superclass out of it.

Comment: **No** When you use raw types it does not automatically get converted to `Object`. look at this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/29944262/4726707] to clarify your doubts about it.

Comment: I agree, but I did not mean to say it was like a generic list of Object. It was just a demonstration. Let me see if I can make it clearer ...

Comment: kindly have a look above as I have completed the code concerning the utilisation of `vies` variable.

Comment: It is hard to see, because it is not a full application, but here is something I have noted: let's say there are two subclasses of Mod, I think that as long as the only method that is called externally is Vie.setMod, you are OK. If Mod.addObs is called other than from Vie  (you will get the warnings again, I suppose) you will have problems. But I am not going to go into it further. I suggest maybe you submit it to the Code Review site, but you would need also to supply a specification of what the goal is of the module (observer/subscriber, I suppose, but a bit  more detail).